# When Run the Project it's always stay in browser waiting for localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

I was trying to attach process for debugging in VS2012 and during this process i have changes in **`Tools-> options -> Debugging ->`** symbols and clicked on load all symbols button . But after that when i  run the project and it's stay in browser ( waiting for localhost ..). What should i do now ..? Could any one help me.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to debug ASP.Net Web Application in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes i was  trying to debug ASP.Net Web Application in Visual Studio .

Comment: If you are debugging your application locally, you do not need to explicitly attach a process to Visual Studio. You just press F5. Am I missing something or are you performing remote debugging?

Comment: i am doing remote debugging.